# Organizational Access To Google Apps From China

Tags: vpn, g-suite, mpls, china

I was tasked in deploying Google Apps for business and I have multiple offices in China which has to be on it.

Anyone knows how can I bypass china's deep packet inspection?

Given my company's health Mpls is very expensive now.

Constantly connecting to vpn poses issues such as having all 500 users in China to log in every time they need to check emails as well as the huge traffic volume at the vpn gateway.

Does proxy server work? Any work around for enterprise solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. Proxy solutions will fail due to the inspection,  so the only way is a VPN.

Comment: How about using tor browser?

Comment: Tor is easily blocked based on IP addresses or protocol, so probably not. It's also pretty slow.

Comment: What about site to site vpn using L2TP?

Comment: Worth a try. I'm not familiar with how much China's firewall blocks.

Answer (score 0):

vpn + remoteapp / xenapp ? You can have too product like netscaler/riverbed to compress furter more the bandwidth. Cant talk for remoteapp, with citrix in a remote office I manage I can serve 100+ peoples on a small isp link (20down/1.5up). The net usage is now really good for such solution.

Comment: I am talking about 500+ users.  Given my resources.. I am afraid that I can't handle this additional remoteapp deployment as I am currently handling three in tandem now.

Comment: You will need some server locally in china then to serve the user, and to sync the data between each server via vpn...